# Javascript SPA ASP.NET Forms Authentication vs storing credentials in Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, single-page-application

I am building a SPA Javascript application with an ASP.NET MVC Web API project backend for dataservices. In the past I have used ASP.NET forms authentication for user security, but I am considering possibly passing username / password to the dataservices every time instead of using any sort of cookies. All communication will be over HTTPS.

2 Questions

1. What are the pros / cons of cookie + session based security vs storing the user credentials in memory in some sort of Javascript object?
2. Are there any recommended ways for keeping credentials (including password) in memory browser side?

Comment: You might want to look into claims based authentication as well.